# GitHub Action command to create an Azure Resource Group from JSON ARM Template

Tags: github, github-actions, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to create and delete an **Azure Resource Group** from the ARM JSON Template. I manually tried to create a **Resource Group** and saved the Template from the **Azure Portal**.

Here is the Json version of the ARM template for the Resource Group:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.1",
    "parameters": {
        "rgName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "rgLocation": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "tags": {
            "type": "object",
            "defaultValue": {}
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
            "location": "[parameters('rgLocation')]",
            "name": "[parameters('rgName')]",
            "properties": {},
            "tags": "[parameters('tags')]"
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

I want is to create a Resource Group and later destroy the Resource Group from a **GitHub Workflow**. I have already some Workflow script to deploy resources in a Resource Group. An example is below:

```
 - name: Deploy Function App Resources
        uses: azure/arm-deploy@v1
        with:
          scope: resourcegroup
          subscriptionId: ${{ env.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
          resourceGroupName: ${{ env.AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP }}
          parameters: ./parameters.json
          template: ./azure-deploy-function-api.json
```

What I want is to create the **Resource Group** before deploying the resources to it. Later I want destroy the whole Resource Group and the resources underneath it.

Comment: What issue do you have?

Comment: I don't know the ARM Template commands to create **Resource Group** with JSON template.

Comment: Did you see this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-github-actions?tabs=userlevel ?

Comment: I followed those instructions to deploy resources in a **Resource Group**, but not how the **Resource Group** itself. The **Resource Group** is created using **Azure CLI** in the instructions. I don't want to use **Azure CLI** but use the JSON file like the resources can be deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deploy resource group you need to change here the scope and then you also don't need `resourceGroupName` parameter. (You simply cannot deploy resource group in resource group scope).

```
 - name: Deploy Function App Resources
        uses: azure/arm-deploy@v1
        with:
          scope: subscription
          subscriptionId: ${{ env.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
          parameters: ./parameters.json
          template: ./azure-deploy-function-api.json
          region: eastus
```

Here you find more details for this [action](https://github.com/Azure/arm-deploy).

Comment: Eventhough I have region name in the parameters file, I get the error: ```Run azure/arm-deploy@v1
  with:
    scope: subscription
    subscriptionId: __
    parameters: ./parameters-rg.json
    template: ./azure-ftp-rg.json
    failOnStdErr: true
Changing subscription context...
Error: Region must be set.```

Comment: Could you share you parameters.json file?

Comment: Here is the parameters file: {"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#","contentVersion": "1.0.0.0","parameters": {"rgName": {"value": "xx.xx.ResourceGroup"},
        "rgLocation": {"value": "eastus"},"tags": {"value": {}}}}

Comment: Please provide also region `region: Conditional Provide the target region, only required for Management Group or Subscription deployments.`

Comment: This is what I have for the resources. The region is set correctly. ```"resources": [{"type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups","apiVersion": "2018-05-01","region": "[parameters('rgLocation')]","name": "[parameters('rgName')]","properties": },"tags": "[parameters('tags')]"}]```

Comment: azure/arm-deploy@v1 requires region parameter when scope is subscription. Check out my edit code.

Comment: After I added region to the scope and again the location in the ```resources.json``` file, the GitHub action succeeds and creates the resources.